# Как регулировать отступы между столбцами на графике chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```js
var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var barChartData = {
  labels: ['2021', '2031', '2035', '2044', '2038'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'title 1',

    borderWidth: 1,
    barPercentage: 1,
    data: [58, 5, 42, 50, 55, 45],
  }, {
    label: 'title 2',

    borderWidth: 1,
    barPercentage: 1,
    data: [45, 45, 25, 55, 44, 95],
  }]

};

window.onload = function() {
  var firstdiagram = document.getElementById('generation').getContext('2d');
  window.myBar = new Chart(firstdiagram, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        align: 'start',
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 12,
          boxHeight: 12
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'x-axis',
      },
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="generation"></canvas>
```

показано цифрами 1 и 2 на скрине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно свойство [`categoryPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/BarControllerDatasetOptions.html#categorypercentage).

Оно принимает значения `0-1` и определяет ширину, которую может занять каждая категория. По умолчанию значение равно `0.8`.

В примере ниже я установил значение равным 1, чтобы между категориями не осталось отступов.

```js
var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var barChartData = {
  labels: ['2021', '2031', '2035', '2044', '2038'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'title 1',

    borderWidth: 1,
    barPercentage: 1,
    categoryPercentage: 1,
    data: [58, 5, 42, 50, 55, 45],
  }, {
    label: 'title 2',

    borderWidth: 1,
    barPercentage: 1,
    categoryPercentage: 1,
    data: [45, 45, 25, 55, 44, 95],
  }]

};

window.onload = function() {
  var firstdiagram = document.getElementById('generation').getContext('2d');
  window.myBar = new Chart(firstdiagram, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        align: 'start',
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 12,
          boxHeight: 12
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'x-axis',
      },
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="generation"></canvas>
```

---

Обратите внимание, что невозможно одновременно использовать свойства [`barThickness`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/bar.html#barthickness) и `barPercentage` / `categoryPercentage`. При использовании `barThickness` последние игнорируются.

Вы должны выбрать, как задавать ширину колонок: конкретным значением или в процентах от свободного места. Длина оси X, вычисляется на основании ширины родительского элемента и количества точек отмеченных на этой оси. Для соответствия какому-либо макету вам придется либо задавать конкретную ширину для `canvas` или блока-обертки.

Если в макете расстояние между точками неодинаковое, вам придется написать [плагин](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/plugins.html) для тонкой настройки отображения графика.

Comment: так то оно так, но если менять barThickness, то будут большие отступы, 
можно просто по центру сделать?

Comment: @towncitybr уточните, пожалуйста, что и по центру чего вы хотите разместить. Если есть возможность, пояснение в виде картинке будет нагляднее.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ha5e1pqo/1/ вот задаю, как Вы сказали. Но также добавляю barThickness. И получается отступ огромный

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/f1z6SLh/photo-2021-07-28-11-15-48.jpg

Comment: Все правильно. Когда задан `barThickness` настройки `barPercentage` и `categoryPercentage` игнорируются. [Документация](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/bar.html#barthickness)

Comment: и как тогда быть? не получится сделать, как в макете?

Comment: @towncitybr, я не знаю и не могу знать, что у вас в макете. Я отвечал на конкретный заданный вопрос. Сейчас я дополнил ответ, чтобы дать вам пищу для размышлений.

Comment: @towncitybr если мое сообщение отвечает на поставленный вами вопрос, пожалуйста, отметьте его решением.